# iframe js issues

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm new to web development and js. I understand some js and jQuery, but not enough to write useful code yet, so I'm hoping to get help here. I'm incorporating some 3rd party web apps into my website via an iFrame (out of pop-up windows and direct links, this is the best way) and have a two part question.

1) The web apps do not allow for direct coding and only allow for a limited number of css styling options. I can upload a background image and change the background color, but I can't make it transparent. I want to adjust the iframe so my website background shows through. According to Firebug, I can simply take the background color option out entirely and the problem is solved.

The issue is that these apps are on a different domain causing cross-domain issues and I imagine most of the code is server side using a Dynamic View Controller (over my head), so incorporating the code into my site directly would probably not work. My "IT Guy" says that we should be able to target the iframe in my .php file and change the styling once the iframe is loaded, since the styles cascade. However, the iframe, as well as everything else on the page, is not named (no classes or ids), so in order to target it, I have to use some sort of ("this").child.child("body") kind of thing. Nothing we have tried has worked so far. If I can target the iframe, I can change other minor issues like buttons that don't display correctly.

2) If I set an iframe height and the iframe displays things longer than the height, it cuts off (obviously). I need the iframe to have a dynamic height, so if the contents of the iframe change, the height of the iframe changes as well. I have seen snippets of code to do this, but I had no idea what I was doing and surprisingly it didn't work. I'm hoping to learn a little js magic if this works.

The test page is located at http://www.nightaliveent.com/builds/1.0/music.php. I can provide my current code if it would help, but I don't want to pollute the board. For reference, the web apps are DJ Intelligence tools, specifically (http://www.djintelligence.com/music).

Thanks for any and all help. Every bit helps, and if I can't get this to work, I will have to discontinue use of the web tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only 'access' content in an iframe when it used on the same domain (security), to try to access it from another domain will never work. Also, it's better not to use iframe (depreciated), use object instead. For some IE versions, you need an iframe because IE is not W3C compliant.

What you can do if you want to load content PARTS from another site is to use ajax and after retrieving the page filter out the content you want. Refer to the `jQuery.ajax` function and you can define success and error callbacks. For example:

```
$.ajax({
   async:true,
   cache:true,
   url: 'your url',
   success:function(s) { alert('the string is: '+s); <filter contents and set target> },
   error:function() { alert('failed'); }
});
```

Hopes it helps.

Comment: This is similar to what we were trying by 'getContents...' in a a .php and including that file. It worked, but the dynamic content of the page didn't load. This method fails and errors "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://nightaliveent.djintelligence.com/music/index.asp. Origin http://nightaliveent.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I wanted to echo the Access-Control state in the fail function so that I can see if it is even set. I have seen mentions of json, and adding an ajax header didn't work. It seems to me that it would have to be controlled via the requested site.

Comment: It is not similar to file_get_contents() and when you want to use that server-side it is better to use curl extension.The reason that is not similar is that this is server-side and the other is client-side. The client-side sends also a 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' header option with it while the server-side does not. Maybe the source is protected to be called by ajax. On the other hand you must pay for the service and you cannot use it for free, so i think what you try to do is illegal. Ask if they got an api to integrate it into your website  but i think when they have an API it is written ASP.

Comment: Also, when i look to your page you want to let the user believe it is your service. I think that is illegal too. Ask for an API or give up and build something yourself.

Comment: Just for clarification, I am paying for the service, so what I am trying to do is not illegal. They provided limited CSS styling tools with a future update planned, so I am working around that until then. Also, there is a copyright mark at the bottom of the page that links to the DJ Intelligence website, so I am not claiming credit as my service. Regardless, I ended up pulling the code in from Firebug and am working on editing the links to pass a file_get_contents script for search results.

Answer (score 1):

> My "IT Guy" says that we should be able to target the iframe in my
> .php file and change the styling once the iframe is loaded, since the
> styles cascade.

There's a lot wrong with that.

- Once the iframe is loaded, it's already client-side in the browser. PHP has no say.
- Styles cascade in the current DOM. Your iFrame is a 'hole' to an entirely different DOM. You have no way to style content in an iFrame that's from another domain.

> I need the iframe to have a dynamic height, so if the contents of the
> iframe change, the height of the iframe changes as well.

I can think of some crazy server-side hacks to maybe calculate that but, alas, you can't do much about that either.

When you are loading other sites into an iFrame, keep in mind - they aren't your sites. It's not your code. For hopefully apparent security reasons, browsers will not let you directly manipulate the content of the iFrames.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle, you are absolutely right that you you cannot access iframe contents if the domain of the parent and child is different, in your case which is true. The parent URL is  "http://www.nightaliveent.com" and the child domain (third party web apps) is "http://www.nightaliveent.djintelligence.com/music"

if you try accessing the iframe contents after the page load it throws following exception.

```
$("iframe").contents()
```

**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.nightaliveent.djintelligence.com/music/ from frame with URL http://www.nightaliveent.com/builds/1.0/music.php. Domains, protocols and ports must match.**